# Trying to parse Json data into model Class this getting error while using codable

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Trying to parse Json data into Model Class "TimeSheetModel" I am getting below error.

**typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "error", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

Response Data Json

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": null,
    "error": null,
    "data": {

    }
}
```

// MARK: - TimeSheetModel

```
struct TimeSheetModel: Codable {
    
    let code: Int?
    let message: String?
    let error: String?
    let timeSheetModel_Data: TimeSheetModel_Data?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case code = "code"
        case message = "message"
        case error = "error"
        case timeSheetModel_Data = "data"

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .code)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
        error = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error)
        timeSheetModel_Data = try values.decodeIfPresent(TimeSheetModel_Data.self, forKey: .timeSheetModel_Data)


    }
}
```

May be I have to handling if else coding for string and Int inside codable model class.

Comment: Are you sure that is the json data you are receiving from your server?  You have shown a null (which is fine for String?) but the error says you received a dictionary. You don't need the custom `init`; the default behaviour should do it for you.

Comment: yeap I am receiving from server side

Comment: Could you instead of just `catch { print(error) }`, instead `catch { print("Error while JSON decoding: \(error)" with response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))") }`?  You seem to think that's the JSON you are getting, but according to the error it's not, so print the JSON when it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error says: `let error: String?` error property is expected to be a `String` type - but server returns a `Dictionary` there.

The JSON you posted seems to have `null` there, but probably error is shown due to different JSON data - one that has `error` object.